# Use probability identity for proof

Tags: probability

> (a) (5 points) Using the identity
>
> $${n+m\choose r}={n\choose0}{m\choose r}+{n\choose1}{m\choose r-1}+\cdots+{n\choose r}{m\choose 0}$$
>
> prove that
>
> $${2n\choose n}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2$$
>
> (b) (5 points) Using the binomial theorem, show that, for $n\ge0$,
>
> $$\sum_{i=o}^n(-1)^i{n\choose i}=0$$

My professor is telling us that we need to know this for the test. I haven't seen this identity before, nor do I even know how to begin applying it to this question. Does anybody have an idea of how I can begin?

Comment: HINT: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ so $\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}$. For question (b), it's really just an immediate application of the binomial theorem.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I apply the identity to that sum?

Comment: Plug the hint into the identity and look at the sum on the right-hand-side. How does it relate to the sum you want?

Comment: So I can plug your hint into the second portion of the identity? I'm not seeing any correlation between the identity and the sum. Maybe I'm not looking at the problem from the right lens.

Comment: $m=n=r...\mbox{       }$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part B, $0=(1-1)^n=\binom{n}{1}1^n-\binom{n}{2}1^{n-1}+\cdots-\binom{n}{n-1}1^{1}+\binom{n}{n}1^0$. However, $1^n=1$, so we are just left with $\binom{n}{1}-\binom{n}{2}+\cdots-\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (-1)^n\binom{n}{i} $.